# when delete data from local storage with splice method, always the last element is deleting

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import styles from "./home.module.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const Home = () => {
  let itemArray = localStorage.getItem("value")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("value"))
    : [];
  const [object, setObject] = useState(itemArray);
  const [objectValue, setObjectValue] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setObjectValue((prevValue) => {
      return { ...prevValue, [name]: value, id: uuidv4() };
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setObject((prevValue) => [...prevValue, objectValue]);
    setObjectValue({ price: "", name: "" });
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(object));
  }, [object]);
  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    itemArray.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(itemArray));
    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="price" onChange={handleChange} value={objectValue.price} />
        <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={objectValue.name} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {object?.map((item, index) => (
          <>
            <h1>{item.price}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>Delete</button>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

when delete data from local storage with splice method, always the last element is deleting.how to solve it?

most of the code is about printing data from input and storing them in an array

When I delete any element immediately after creating the data,also the last element is deleted.this issue does not occur after manually refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not updating your object in handleDelete if you don't use window reload. Better to use ID for deleting entry and then udpate object.

You can do this (from handleDelete):

```
  const handleDelete = (idToDelete) => {
    const updatedObject = object.filter(({ id }) => id !== idToDelete);
    setObject(updatedObject);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="price" onChange={handleChange} value={objectValue.price} />
        <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={objectValue.name} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {object?.map((item, index) => (
          <>
            <h1>{item.price}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>Delete</button>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: I have updated the code, ideally, use should use id for deleting and updating. Actually, whenever you add any new entry it's not added in itemArray and when you were deleting you were setting local storage using itemArray which is missing data. Always try to use one source of truth. Don't mix them.